# Java FlyServer Fly Object space

Tags: java, objectspace

I have developed a Java application using The ‘Fly’ Object Space.

After writing an object from the FlyServer to the FlySpace, there is a line of code as follows:

```
long res = space.write(dc, 10000);
```

Can someone explain to me what this line of code does?

Comment: *"FlyServer to the FlySpace.."* WTF?  When SO has no tag for it, that is a good hint to link to what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It writes an object into the fly space which will survive 10000 ms. Examples here https://github.com/fly-object-space/fly-java/tree/master/src/com/zink/fly/example

More on fly here http://flyobjectspace.com/